# Can I get full functionality of full Python without ArcGIS for GIS scypting?

Tags: python, arcgis

ArcGIS is come with Python, that allow incredible wide functionality -- allow to do about 100% of ArcGIS with scripting with Arcpy, without running ArcGIS.

But I have question. How it's done? Can I get such functionality without installation of ArcGIS? If yeas what I should to install to get such functionality with my Python?

If no, could you explain how it's done? Does Python that come with ArcGIS use GIS dlls for geo processing?

P.S. I know about gdal\qgis, but I would like electrically hight level scripting that allow me by Arcpy from ArcGIS. It's much easier than gdal have.

Comment: In short...if ArcGIS isn't installed on the machine you are running Python on, you can't access the functionality within ArcGIS since it uses the arcpy to put python wrappers around ArcObjects the c code upon which the whole program is built.  You will have to use open source programs, most of which support python at varying degrees.  If something is specific to ArcMap...you are out of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely possible!

ArcGIS is nice, but expensive and pretty academic. If you're looking for an open-source alternative that allows you to use python scripting pretty seamlessly I would highly recommend [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/).

Here is the official [PyQGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/) tutorial, that should show you how to accomplish anything you really need.

Comment: As far as I know all GDAL functionality is done with GDAL. I really do not like it's after very easy Arcpy from ArcGIS.

Comment: @Suliman not the case. PyQGIS is a great alternative to dealing directly with GDAL